# PHP create directory name with forward slash

Tags: php

I'm beginner in php. With a scenario i wanted to create directory with forward slash in name(09/01/2017). How can i resolve it?

```
$my_date = "09/01/2017"
$new_path = "../Images/".$my_date;

if(!file_exists($new_path)) {
    mkdir($new_path , 0777);
}
```

EDIT: I'm using macos with php server in it. In macos it is possible to create folder with slashes.

Comment: `<?php
$my_date = "09/01/2017/";
$new_path = "../Images/".$my_date;

if (!mkdir($new_path, 0777, true)) {
    die('Failed to create folders...');
}
?>
`

Comment: Don't create a directory name with a forward slash. I'm sure you *can*, but you shouldn't. Replace those slashes with dashes or delete them and save future you a whole lot of headaches.

Comment: Just checking, but is that date _9th of Jan, 2017_ (Europe, Australia, etc format) or _1st of Sept, 2017_ (American format)?

Comment: @Tigger, its an *9th of Jan, 2017*

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$my_date = "09/01/2017";
$new_path = "images/".$my_date;
if (!is_dir($new_path))
{
    mkdir($new_path , 0777,true);
}
?>
```

mkdir($new_path , 0777,true);//true for recursive directory creation.

In your case if you create directory with 09/01/2017 it will be created

```
File Tree:

images
--09
 --01
  --2017
```

because file system not allowed forward slash as directory name.Instead of this you can create 09012017 or 09-01-2017.

Comment: hmm interesting. Well I'm running mac os where slash in directory name is possible. Is there a way in php to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Milan Mendpara i would like to tell you that you can not make any folder with name char /:*?"<>|, even you can not make a directory in you OS as well. when you try it in you OS then below case will arise

[image]

So i think you should change your directory from 09/01/2017 to 09-01-2017, IN my case i dont have ../'Image' directory so i just make a directory where my php file is present so below is you code

```
<?php
    $my_date = "09-01-2017";
    $tempDir = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $my_date;   // __DIR__  means a path where your php file is present and DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR means __DIR__.'/' and then give you directory name like __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $my_date
    if(!is_dir($temp_dir)){
        mkdir($temp_dir);
    }
```

?>

Comment: Oh i see, good to know that! well I'm running mac os, where i am able to create folder with slashes. I will change it to dahses instead. But wondering if theres a way to create a folder with slashes in my mac?

Comment: I don't use mac Os buddy sorry for that